# Svcutil.exe metadata showing incorrect path in the browser

Tags: wcf, wcf-data-services, wcf-binding, wcf-ria-services, wcf-security

We created a wcf service with two endpoints one for http  for internal users and the other for https for external users.

When the service is viewed in the browser using https , svcutil.exe metadata path is pointing to http instead of https. Moreover, I am not able to add this service through service reference screen as well.  I configured the wcf service like in the [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh556232%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). How to correct the svcutil.exe path.

Comment: Show us some code. Service contract definition, app.config details, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Its need some extra effort in your web.config to enable get metatdata via https, say add 'httpsGetEnabled="true"' in element serviceMetadata.

```
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior>
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```

Then the metadata path would be correct.

Reference: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/c7fd51a2-773e-41d4-95a0-244e925597fe/wcf-wsdl-generated-paths-for-xsdschema-wsdlimport-soapaddress-wrong-for-wcf-behind-a-firewall?forum=wcf